# Какое сказуемое?

Tags: синтаксис

"Научить любить невозможно". В безличном предложении такое сказуемое. Как его можно назвать?

Answer (score 1):

***Научить любить невозможно***

1. Предложение безличное.
2. Сказуемое выражено модальным предикативом (словом категории состояния), к нему примыкает инфинитив "научить".

Примечание. Модальные предикативы без инфинитива не употребляются.

3. Научить (чему? что делать?) — дополнение.

Ответ. Сказуемое выражено **модальным предикативом** с примыкающим к нему инфинитивом.

[https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf](https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf), стр. 91.

Comment: Разве не инфинитив ‟научить” является подлежащим? Вот первые предложения по поиску ‟инфинитив-подлежащее”: ‟Радоваться жизни — огромный талант”, ‟Верить лжецу бесполезно”. Разве тогда это не безличное предложение, так как безличное — это когда отсутствует подлежащее? Разве ‟невозможно” — это не краткая форма прилагательного ‟невозможное”, а также составное именное сказуемое. А ‟любить” это не несогласованное определение? Я прямо не согласен с каждой строчкой, что вы написали. Но я не уверен, потому что детально не разбирался во всем этом кале.

Comment: Я же ссылку дала, вот и разбирайтесь. Лучше всего прочитать книгу с самого начала и законспектировать основное содержание.

Comment: Не не не, я уже говорил, что разбираться в вопросах членов предложения — мартышкин труд. Какая разница между этим предложением и предложением: «Верить лжецу бесполезно», где подлежащее ‟верить”, согласно учебнику?

Comment: Верить лжецу бесполезно, а бегать по утрам полезно. Это как раз  примеры из книжки по теме «двусоставные предложения». Вы уже догадались, что инфинитив здесь в роли подлежащего?

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, сказуемое здесь опущенный глагол "есть": научить любить [есть] невозможно. Возможно, "невозможно" также является частью сказуемого.